# Editing Microsoft Word documents in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

We are converting legacy VB application to ASP.Net application.
We have the several word documents stored in SQL server database.
Users should be able to edit the word documents and store it in the database.
I am trying to use iFrame whose source would be the word document in the server.
Users will have MS word installed on client PC but not on the server.
But how can i get the changed file in ASP.Net and store it back on the server.

Please advise me.

Regards,
Mugil.

Comment: Follow this link for steps and code implementation. http://steptodotnet.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-edit-word-document-using-aspnet.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit documents in MS Word and store them online, you probably have to write a plugin for Word. A simple and crude solution would be to require the users to save the document locally and then upload it via your website.
You probably want to take a look at [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/pages/default.aspx).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of the use of Sharepont to avoid expensive development time over something that already exists ( Sharepoint ). If there is a working legacy application working it should be easy enough to convert it ( if they really want to go down that expensive time consuming path ).